# What kind of dyno is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Can anyone help me out. Just pick this dyno up and have no idea what kind it is.

Comment: It looks like a purple Dyno to me.

Comment: @RoboKaren no its definitely blue.

Comment: @gooder you might want to invest some time browsing through http://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/dyno/  and see if you find a match.

Comment: @Criggie I don't know what you're talking about. It's clearly white and gold.

Answer (score 2):

The high spoke-count wheels look nice but are mostly for show rather than increased load capacity.  Notice the front wheel is laced radially and the rear is laced crossed.  As such this front wheel would not suit a brake.

At least one tyre has been replaced because of the colour and tread difference.

Otherwise its a fairly neutral BMX, not intended for stunts or trials.  If you like it, just ride it and maintain it.

Since you've "just picked it up"  try asking the person selling it.  If they're the original owner they will know the most.  Original paperwork is always a selling point for a bike too, and a service history.  I know exactly how many km are in my chain and cassette.